# How to turn responsive design off when scripting an SVG export in Illustrator CC 17.1?

Tags: javascript, svg, adobe-illustrator

When exporting SVG files from illustrator 17.1 they added a responsive design check box.  This is a problem because they also made it default to being checked.  They haven't updated any documentation that I've seen, and I need to be able to turn off this option when scripting a batch export.  I expected it to be something like (javascript):

```
    var options = new ExportOptionsSVG();
    options.responsive = false;
```

That doesn't do it.  Extendscript toolkit is still targeting Illustrator 17.0, so the auto complete for it doesn't exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: Having the same issue right now! Seems like they still haven't added this capability